# Excel Running Total if data in current month

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to write a formula in Excel that will compare 2015 totals to 2016 totals and projections.  If there is a value in the rows for January, February, March and April, I want the 2015 sum of those same months.  Then the same for the projected

Screen capture of excel file

[image]

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I like to use SUMPRODUCT() for something like this:

Projected:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$5:$B$16<>"")*$A$5:$A$16)
```

Actual:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$5:$B$16<>"")*$D$5:$D$16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  So simple and easy works exactly like I need.

Comment: @AmberMing please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will mark this question as answered.